# Android Studio Instant run not working using java 8 in android

Tags: android, android-studio, java-8, android-instant-run

Using java 8 for concise Lambda expression etc but downside is instant run not working. `buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"`

```
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
```

how to enable instant run with java 8 features

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From offical documenataion:

> Known Issues
>   Instant Run does not currently work with Jack and will be disabled while using the new toolchain.

https://developer.android.com/preview/j8-jack.html

Comment: Would you recommend using Retrolambda until it's supported? Cause it will be a huge loss of time if instant run isnt working... What do you think?

Comment: Is it known when Instant Run will become available for Jack?

Comment: Its 2017 and still nothing. Shame on them. We spend more time worrying about IDE issues than our coding problems themselves.

Comment: Jack is no longer required. Built-in support is added with default tool-chain in https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2017/04/android-studio-24-preview-4-is-now.html

Answer (score 4):

Patience is a virtue. Support for Java 1.8 will be built in Android studio without the need of any configuration or external libraries in the near future (weeks from now)

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/03/future-of-java-8-language-feature.html